# Extract subdocuments array from a MondoDB document using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've a MongoDB document like this-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("546d96b861cbf86e90544bc4"),
"Hierarchy" : {
                "Region" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Name" : "Dhaka",
                                    "Area" : [ 
                                                {
                                                    "Name" : "Dhaka North"
                                                }, 
                                                {
                                                    "Name" : "Dhaka South"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Name" : "Khulna",
                                    "Area" : []
                                }
                            ]
                }
}
```

Using MongoDB C# driver, I would like to extract all **Area** from **Region** element where `Region.Name="Dhaka"`.

I googled, but did not found anything that can help me.

Would you please help me?

Comment: Are you to extract this data from a single object? i.e. just the document you put here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var fields = Fields.Exclude("_id").Include("Hierarchy.Region.Area");
var queryString = Query.EQ("Hierarchy.Region.Name", "Dhaka");
var result = collection.Find(queryString).SetFields(fields).SetFields().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the mongo driver for nothing but getting the object. To extract the data from it you can just use linq to objects.

```
var obj = GetObjectFromMongo(...);
var areas = obj.Hierarchy.Region.Where(r => r.Name == "Dhaka").Select(r => r.Area);
```

Comment: I've got the idea. Would you please post the detail of GetObjectFromKMongo()? Sorry to bother, I'm very new to MongoDB.

Comment: I won't because it's off topic, you should google "how to get object from mongo db c#". This has been answered many times.